# Anonymize arbitrary Unicode text to script-specific placeholders

Tags: unicode

When reporting bugs in one of my programs (which handles specialized XML files containing Bible text, which may contain copyrighted or otherwise protected material), there is an option to submit an anonymized XML file with the report. As some bugs only happen with certainly formatted text in the fields, punctuation should be preserved and only letters and digits anonymized.

At the moment, the code first identifies fields that should be anonymized, then iterates over each character and replaces uppercase Latin letters by `X`, lowercase Latin letters by `x`, Digits by `0` and Greek letters by `Χ` / `χ`.

Now I got a report that it does not work with Cyrillic text. I fixed it now by replacing any Unicode letters by `X` or `x`, but that will change the script of the letters unneccessarily and may make bugs unreproducible.

I could now of course add another special case for Cyrillic to solve this, and wait for the next bug report.

But I wondered if anybody else may have already compiled a list or database of "anonymizing" characters for each script available in Unicode. Or found a way to extract it from the UnicodeData either included in Java or provided by the Unicode consortium. Preferrably as a Java library, but any other file that can be used from Java should be fine, too.

Comment: Apply [Unicode regular expressions](https://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Categories)…

Comment: Applying unicode regular expressions would be a solution in case anyone could come up with a source where to find the correct "X" character in all the 168 combinations of Script and Letter category listed in [Scripts.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/9.0.0/ucd/Scripts.txt). But I did not find such a list on Unicode page or CLDR anywhere...

Comment: As I see some people don't believe this question belongs to this site: Suggestions which other SE community to ask would also be welcome. Linguistics.SE seems to have some writing-system questions, but more non-technical ones

Comment: Java 4 and later include comprehensive support for regular expressions through the standard `java.util.regex` package. Java 5 fixes some bugs and adds support for *Unicode blocks*. Java 7 adds [Unicode scripts](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#script).